# Python JSON list parsing

Tags: python, json

I have a code that tests if a json config file exists - if so, loads the values, if not, creates it with raw input.

```
import os
import json

if os.path.isfile("config.json"):
    config = open('config.json', 'r')
    confjson = json.loads(config)
    fruit = confjson['fruit']
    vegetables = confjson['vegetables']

    print "fruit:", fruit
    print "vegetables:", vegetables
else:
    fruit = raw_input("Enter your favourite fruit: ")
    vegetables = raw_input("Enter your favourite vegerables (separated by space): ")
    vegetables = vegetables.split(" ")
    config = open('config.json', 'w')
    config.write('{"fruit":"'+fruit+'","vegetables":'+str(vegetables)+'}')
```

The writing to file part works well:

```
>>> 
Enter your favourite fruit: apple
Enter your favourite vegerables (separated by space): carrot potato
>>>
```

However, when I now restart the program, I get the following error:

```
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dell/Desktop/test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    confjson = json.loads(config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
>>>
```

I also tried replacing "loads" with "load", but got an error also:

```
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dell/Desktop/test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    confjson = json.load(config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
>>>
```

Now, when I replaced the list with a regular string, all worked fine - so it's the list of vegetables that is causing it, however - what way could I change it so it works?

Comment: You should certainly `load`, not `loads` - it's a file, not a string. And why don't you create a dictionary and `dump` it instead of trying to create your own JSON, which evidently isn't working (missing quotes)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually, I realized the missing quotes now and fixed it. I also moved the "vegetables = vegetables.split(" ")" to be in the load part, instead of the write part. It works now.

Comment: If you created a dict `{str: list of str}` you could `dump` the whole thing, and wouldn't need to `split` when you `load`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You want to load from a file, which you can do with: `confjson = json.load(config)`
2. Use `json.dumps()` to properly encode the dictionary into json with: `config.write(json.dumps({'fruit': fruit, 'vegetables': vegetables}))`

(The issue with your method is that the vegetables will be single-quoted, while json strings are double quoted)

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure of using `json.dumps()` with write. This is the answer I really needed because I realized some obvious mistakes soon after asking.

Comment: yout could even use `json.dump` directly, like `json.dump({...  }, config)`.

Answer (score 2):

When writing, you need to enclose the values also in double quotes. You current code would write a file like

```
{"fruit": apple, "vegetables": tomatoes}
```

This is incorrect, since "apple" and "tomatoes" also need quotes.

I would suggest using the `json` package also for writing (using `json.dumps`) since this will also take care of escaping the string values (i.e. if the user enters a double quote...)

For loading, you need to use `json.load` instead of `loads`: the latter expects a string argument, the former loads the json from a file (or a file like resp. stream object)

Comment: I already fixed the quotes. But thanks anyways. I like jh314's answer more because it explains with an example.

Answer (score 1):

1. json.loads takes a string not a json file
2. Rather than attempting to format a json file by hand, you could just write the thing as a dict and dump to file. Here's a quick take on it

   ```
   if os.path.isfile("config.json"):
        config = open('config.json', 'r')
       confjson = json.load(config)
       fruit = confjson['fruit']
       vegetables = confjson['vegetables']    

       print "fruit:", fruit
       print "vegetables:", vegetables
   else:
       fruit = raw_input("Enter your favourite fruit: ")
       vegetables = raw_input("Enter your favourite vegerables (separated by space): ")
       vegetables = vegetables.split(" ")
       config = open('config.json', 'w')
       res = {"fruit":fruit,"vegetables":vegetables}
       json.dump(res, config)
       config.close()
   ```